# c# WPF координаты окна в рамках MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В WPF у окна есть несколько свойств, отвечающие за его расположение на экране: Left, Top. Как в рамках MVVM изменять эти свойства, учитывая, что обычная привязка не работает, т.к. вылетает исключение????

Comment: В чем связь между координатами окна и MVVM? Координаты, цвет, форма окна - это чисто вьюшные задачи

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, у вас ошибка в привязке. Вот рабочий пример, всё прекрасно привязывается.

VM-часть:

```
class MainVM : VM
{
    double x, y;
    public double X { get => x; set => Set(ref x, value); }
    public double Y { get => y; set => Set(ref y, value); }
    public ICommand Run { get; }

    async void Move()
    {
        var centerX = X;
        var centerY = Y;
        var R = 50;
        while (true)
        {
            const double delta = Math.PI * 10 / 180;
            for (double angle = 0; angle < 2 * Math.PI; angle += delta)
            {
                X = centerX + R * Math.Cos(angle);
                Y = centerY + R * Math.Sin(angle);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
            }
        }
    }

    public MainVM() { Run = new RelayCommand(o => Move()); }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Тест" Height="250" Width="250"
        Top="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}" Left="{Binding Y, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Position: ("/><!--
            --><Run Text="{Binding X, StringFormat=0.00, Mode=OneWay}"/><!--
            --><Run Text=", "/><!--
            --><Run Text="{Binding Y, StringFormat=0.00, Mode=OneWay}"/><!--
            --><Run Text=")"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <Button Command="{Binding Run}">Run</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Сначала я перемещаю окно, и VM-координаты обновляются автоматически. Затем я меняю координаты в VM, и положение окна подхватывает их:

[image: танцуем и пляшем, ура!]

Comment: Так чтобы VM не знала, вероятно, не получится, т.к мне нужно чтобы моё окно, как бы следовало за другим окном, координаты которого я получаю посредством WinAPI.

Comment: @РазДва: А, ну раз координаты окна — часть доменной логики приложения, то тогда в порядке.

Comment: Есть проблема: По вашему коду у меня привязка не работает, я вообще плохо понимаю как она у ВАС работает т.к мне, что привязать какое либо свойство сначала нужно объявить пространство имён, в котором лежит VM, после этого закинуть этот класс в ресурсы окна, дать ему ключ. и только после этого, по ключу, обращаться к этой VM. Иначе привязка просто не работает.

Comment: @РазДва: Странно. У меня работает. И по MVVM View устанавливать себе DataContext не имеет права, так что помещать VM в ресурсы неправильно. Привязывайте DataContext снаружи.

Comment: @РазДва: Или вы вообще не устанавливаете `DataContext`? Тогда установите.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. XAML разметка:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SpeechPoker:MainViewModel x:Key="MVM"/>
    <local:BoolToProfitConverter x:Key="ProfitConverter" />
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibleConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Left>
    <Binding Path="Left" Source="{StaticResource MVM}" Mode="TwoWay"/>
</Window.Left>

<Window.Top>
    <Binding Path="Top" Source="{StaticResource MVM}" Mode="TwoWay"/>
</Window.Top>
```